# pr2_teleop_booth moved to pr2_teleop_general

Tags: teleop, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a hard time finding the pr2_teleop_booth package, so I'm just putting it in here hopefully to save others some time. Where did the pr2_teleop_booth package move to?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31983/pr2_teleop_booth-moved-to-pr2_teleop_general/) by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2012-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The pr2_teleop_booth package renamed to pr2_teleop_general:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_teleop_general

---

Originally posted by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) with karma: 735 on 2012-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0